# change event in jQuery, Used For SelectedIndexChanged in ASP.NET DropDown List

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am developing a server control in C#. I am trying to read via jQuery when the selectedindexchanges on a drop down menu.

All my research has alluded to using the change event. As a result, I built a simple test via an alert to see whether this event gets called correctly. Here is my script:

```
 var builder = new StringBuilder();
 builder.Append("$(document).ready(function() {");
 builder.Append("$($='_ddlMyTest').change(function() {");
 builder.Append("alert('hello');");
 builder.Append("}");
 builder.Append(");");
 builder.Append("}");
 builder.Append(");");
```

I call this script in my control to register startup scripts:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "myfunction", String.Format("<script type='text/javascript'> {0}</script>", builder), false);
```

I know jQuery is registered correctly, and the above is registered correctly if I just throw an alert in the `$(document).ready`I do see it in my browser.

My rendered HTML for that element looks like a normal select. I have also tried passing in the ClientID rather than using the `$='_ddlMyTest'` to no effect. I have made sure after that this match.

My question is, does this change event work for when the index is changing in an asp.net dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very important thing to note here is that, in the browser, and from the perspective of JavaScript, there is *no such thing* as "an ASP.NET DropDown".  The HTML element is a `select`, no different from any other `select`.

What concerns me is this selector:

```
$($='_ddlMyTest')
```

I've never seen that `$=` syntax before, and it's not clear to me what that's even intending to do.  If the `id` of the client-side element is `_ddlMyTest` then the selector would be:

```
$('#_ddlMyTest')
```

If, as you suggest, the client-side `id` is *different* (WebForms has a history of doing that), then you'd need to make sure you're using that `id`.  How did you attempt that?  I'm not really certain *how* you'd get that from within the context of that `StringBuilder` in the server-side code, but presumably if there's a `ClientID` property then it would look something like:

```
builder.Append("$('#" + ClientID + "').change(function() {");
```

or:

```
builder.Append(string.Format("$('#{0}').change(function() {", ClientID));
```

(not sure if the `{` characters in the JavaScript code would mess with `string.Format` though) or:

```
builder.Append("$('#");
builder.Append(ClientID);
builder.Append("').change(function() {");
```

Whichever you think is more clear, they all essentially should produce the same result with minor performance differences.  The point being that it would need to happen in the server-side code since the rendered JavaScript has no knowledge of the `ClientID` property.

Comment: To get the clientID, I added the controls to the WebControl.Controls, then read the value of ClientID from the local variable. In the rendered html, it looks right...ill try some of your suggestions!

Comment: @user3010406: Glad I could help!  I guess it was just that `$=` syntax in the selector, which may have even been breaking a lot more if it was re-assigning the `$` variable in a larger scope :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but you may also use the jQuery "find" syntax $("[id$='ddlMyTest']") to find the control that "ends with" ddlMyTest.
A lot of times, this is more convenient than finding the ClientId from code behind.